# Map dentro de otro Map

Tags: c++, map

Estoy intentando acceder a un `map` que está contenido en otro `map`, pero me da error.

El código es el siguiente:

```
map<string, map<string, list<string>>>::iterator iter;
map<string, list<string>>::iterator iterdos;
map<string, list<string>> m_spm;
pair<string, map<string, list<string>> > p_aux;
pair<string, list<string>> p_auxdos,spm;
//cout<<"PALABRA CLAVE ENCONTRADA "<<palabra_clave_encontrada<<endl;
iter = palabra_paginas.find(palabra_clave_encontrada);

if(iter==palabra_paginas.end()){
  //Añadir un elemento nuevo
  //buscamos si esta el dominio
  p_aux.first=palabra_clave_encontrada;
  spm.first=dominio;
  spm.second.push_back(nodo);
  p_aux.second.insert(spm);
  palabra_paginas.insert(p_aux);
}
else{
  m_spm=palabra_paginas->second;
  iterdos=m_spm.find(dominio);
  if(iterdos==palabra_paginas->second.end()){
    p_auxdos.first=dominio;
    p_auxdos.second.push_back(nodo);
    palabra_paginas->second.insert(p_auxdos);
  }
  else{
    iter->second->second.push_back(nodo);
  }
}
```

Cuando intento acceder a `palabra_paginas->second` me da error, al igual que en las siguientes:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:442:32 error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std:map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::_cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>

    m_spm=palabra_paginas->second;
                         ^
main.cpp:444:38: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std:map<std::__cxx11:::basic_string<char>, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::_cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>

    if(iterdos==palabra_paginas->second.end()){
                               ^
main.cpp:450:25: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11__::list<std::basic_string<char> > >

    iter->second.push_back(nodo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
map<string, map<string, list<string>>>::iterator iter;

iter = palabra_paginas.find(palabra_clave_encontrada);
```

Podemos suponer entonces que `palabra_paginas` está declarado tal que:

```
map<string, map<string, list<string>>> palabra_paginas;
```

Bien, con esto en mente, la siguiente instrucción es incorrecta:

```
palabra_paginas->second.insert(p_auxdos);
```

¿Por qué? Varios motivos:

- `palabra_paginas` no es un puntero, luego no es posible usar con dicho objeto el operador `->`.
- `palabra_paginas` no dispone de ningun miembro llamado `second`.

Quizás lo que pretendes en este punto es actuar sobre el iterador, no sobre el mapa en sí:

```
iter->second.insert(p_auxdos);
```

Pero es complicado de confirmar porque él ejemplo que expones no es precisamente claro.

Answer (score 2):

Este es un ejemplo perfecto de cómo usar alias de tipos mejora la legibilidad del código y reduce los errores, empecemos por darles nombres a tus tipos:

```
using lista_texto = list<string>;
using mapa_listas = map<string, lista_texto>;
using gran_mapa_listas = map<string, mapa_listas>;
```

Así pues, tus primeras líneas quedarían de la siguiente manera:

```
gran_mapa_listas::iterator iter;
mapa_listas::iterator iterdos;
mapa_listas m_spm;

gran_mapa_listas::value_type p_aux;
mapa_listas::value_type p_auxdos,spm;
```

Lo cuál es ligeramente más legible. No se cuál es el tipo de `palabra_paginas` porque no muestras su declaración, pero por lo que deduzco del código que has publicado es un mapa (pues usas `std::map::find` sobre él).

Si es un mapa,no tendrá el operador flecha (`->`) sobrecargado, así pues cualquier línea en que escribas `palabra_paginas->...` no tendrá sentido.

Por lo que veo lo usas como si fuera un iterador de mapa, pues escribes `palabra_paginas->second` en varios puntos pero no es un par ni un iterador así que forzosamente te va a fallar.

Seguramente debes cambiar `palabra_paginas` por alguno de los iteradores que declaras al principio, repasa el código.